# How to create a model with multiply choices with custom text?

Tags: python, django

I'm building a simple quiz app. I want to add an ability to add multiple choices (with custom user text) for each question in the admin panel. So the user can create a question and on the same page add as many answers as he needs. What is the best way to realize it?

I know that I can add another model for answers and make a relationship with questions model. But it's not exactly what I want to achieve.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is *literally* the example given in the tutorial.

Comment: @Dan ah sorry, I see now. It's at the end of the tutorial. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Emmm. Then what do you want to achieve ?)
You've just described the right way to do it.

It was answered here:

1. [django quiz app model for multiple choice questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47867760/django-quiz-app-model-for-multiple-choice-questions)
2. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114962/model-classes-for-a-quiz-app-in-django/115014

If you want, you can check out how it's done in this popular django app:
https://github.com/tomwalker/django_quiz/blob/master/multichoice/models.py

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer in the official Django tutorial (thanks for comments) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial07/